# Converting time in PHP?

Tags: php

How do i convert the time which I pull from a database `2009-09-27 23:58:54` to the following time using PHP `Sep 27, 2009`.

Answer (score 11):

`<?php echo date('M j, Y', strtotime('2009-09-27 23:58:54')); ?>`

Answer (score 9):

If you're using MySQL then I would advise you use the MySQL [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function, something like this:

```
SELECT date_format(date, '%b %e,%Y') AS `formatted_date` FROM `table_name`;
```

Comment: Though not an exact answer to the question ("in PHP"), this would be preferable if, as you stipulated, the OP is using MySQL. More efficient by far.

Comment: good point, guess i figured that if he's pulling it  from a database in the first place this would be a more elegant solution. since he's using php, odds are he will be on mysql too.

Answer (score 7):

In PHP you can use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) or in MySQL you can use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to get the date into a timestamp.

You can then use the [date](http://php.net/date) function to format it as you want:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($myDate);
$dateStr = date('M j, Y', $timestamp);
```